# Получить несколько строк из таблицы MySQL/MariaDB с помощью PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

У меня есть таблица такого типа:

```
+----------+----------+------------+
| one      | two      | three      |
+----------+----------+------------+
| red      | blue     | data       |
| red      | blue     | data_two   |
+----------+----------+------------+
```

Мне нужно получить `data` и `data_two`, для этого я написал следующий код:

```
$dbs = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'database');
$sql = "SELECT three FROM table WHERE one = 'red' AND two = 'blue';";
$res = mysqli_query($dbs, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
```

После этого массив `$row` выглядит так:

```
Array ( [0] => data [three] => data )
```

То есть я получаю только `data`, но если выполнить такой же SQL запрос в консоли, я получаю и `data` и `data_two`:

```
MariaDB [database]> SELECT three FROM table WHERE one = 'red' AND two = 'blue';
+------------+
| three      |
+------------+
| data       |
| data_two   |
+------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Подскажите, как можно получить обе *dat’ы* в PHP?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `mysqli_result::fetch_array -- mysqli_fetch_array — Выбирает одну строку из результирующего набора и помещает ее в ассоциативный массив, обычный массив или в оба`посмотрите примеры, читать надо до получения false. https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Добавьте такую конструкцию:

```
$rows = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```